# Is it possible to create a trigger that updates certain rows based on certain conditions?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Tables:

- Employee
- Orders
- Customer

An employee can take orders from 0 or more customers, and a customer can place 1 or many orders. In this sense, Orders is the bridge between Employee and Customer, and contains Employee_no and Customer_no as FKs.

I would like to create a trigger that after a new customer record has been added to Customer table, updates the Orders table in the following way:

- First five customers are assigned to Employee_no 1, for instance.
- Second five customers are assigned to Employee_no 2, for instance.

... and so on till the last Employee_no (say for instance 10)

And then another five customers are assigned to Employee_no 1, again.

So, it goes round and round and the employees take turns to handle customers.

Comment: that sounds like a horrible design, scalability is going to be huge problem when you expand, better look into implementing functionality like that with external queue or stack

Comment: Why would a new customer trigger updating orders to existing customers?!

Comment: What teacher ask for this kind of horrible homework?

Comment: @ everyone: Well, basically I am supposed to develop a plan to assign an employee to customer using queue structure.

Comment: p.s. I am not sure if the best plan would be to create a trigger, that's why I need suggestions. Please!

Comment: The logic could be part of the procedure handling the INSERT into the CUSTOMERS table, but the employee is a point of concern.  There's always staff turnover - over time, after employee #2 leaves, who's the new #2?  I'll always be #6, cookie to whomever gets the reference :)

Comment: @ OMG Ponies: I understand what you mean. Checking to see if employee #2 is fired or retired is chapter two of my project. For now, I need to make a plan so that one employee is not overwhelmed with 100 customers at a time instead all employees are queued to handle new customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you would like a trigger on the Order table, rather than the Customer table. Perhaps something like this would work?

- Write a query to get number of complete multiples of 5 orders the employees has in the Order table.
- Use this query to write a function returning the employee ID for the employee that is next in turn to get assigned an order. Test the function to ensure it seems to do what you want.
- Write a trigger on insert using the function to set employee_id in Orders table.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will work on it, and see how far I get.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a trigger on the order table that determines the employee with the least customers. That prevents you from having to re-evaluate all existing orders.

```
create or replace trigger trigger_orders
before insert on orders
for each row
begin
  if :new.employee_no is null
  then
    ... determine employee with least orders and assign this no to :new.employee_no ...
  end if;
end;
```